# How to show keyboard on start dialog

Tags: kotlin, dialog, keyboard

When dialog opens keyboard is hidden. I want to show keyboard automatically when dialog opens.

```
 val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_profile_name_surname_dialog, null)
                val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(mDialogView).setTitle("Change Name and Surname")
                val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can so something like this. It will open keyboard forcefully .

```
   { 
            val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_profile_name_surname_dialog, null)
            val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(mDialogView).setTitle("Change Name and Surname")
            val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

         mDialogView?.let { v ->

            val imm = context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm?.let { it.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0) }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Finally!! Thank bro! :)